What is the correct HTML rel attribute value for an "Imprint" hyperlink?
In some European countries, it is required by law (regulations vary) to have an "Imprint" page (often referred to as "Impressum" in German-speaking countries) on the website that contains certain information (e.g., contact, copyright, and company details).
In my HTML, I usually mark up <a> elements with the appropriate rel attribute values.
For example, I found the following appropriate values for my hyperlinks pointing to the "Privacy" and "Terms and Conditions" pages of my website:
<a href="/privacy" rel="privacy-policy">GDPR</a>
<a href="/terms-conditions" rel="terms-of-service">General Terms and Conditions</a>

But I have not found an imprint or similar value in the Link Relations registry and Microformats rel values, or any information on what would be correct to use for such a hyperlink.
As an alternative, I thought of using a combination of author and license, like this:
<a href="/imprint" rel="author license">Imprint</a>

I'm just not sure if this is the proper way or if there is a better option that is used as an industry standard.
Is it advisable to propose a new imprint value to one of the respective registries, and if so, where and how is this done?
Take the Squarespace's imprint ("EU Legal") page as an example.
